# How to fix error running local Otsu threshold example?

Tags: python, matplotlib, scikit-image

I am very new to Python. I am trying to run this script:

https://scikit-image.org/docs/0.12.x/auto_examples/segmentation/plot_local_otsu.html

But, I'm getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/janine/Downloads/plot_local_otsu.py", line 37, in <module>
  fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, 2, figsize=(8, 5), sharex=True, sharey=True,
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/_api/deprecation.py", line 471, in wrapper
  return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 1440, in subplots
  axs = fig.subplots(nrows=nrows, ncols=ncols, sharex=sharex, sharey=sharey,
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/_api/deprecation.py", line 471, in wrapper
  return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/figure.py", line 908, in subplots
  axs = gs.subplots(sharex=sharex, sharey=sharey, squeeze=squeeze,
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/gridspec.py", line 307, in subplots
  axarr[row, col] = figure.add_subplot(
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/figure.py", line 781, in add_subplot
  ax = subplot_class_factory(projection_class)(self, *args, **pkw)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_subplots.py", line 36, in __init__
  self._axes_class.__init__(self, fig, [0, 0, 1, 1], **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/_api/deprecation.py", line 471, in wrapper
  return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py", line 648, in __init__
  self.update(kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 1064, in update
  ret.append(func(v))
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py", line 1531, in set_adjustable
  _api.check_in_list(["box", "datalim"], adjustable=adjustable)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/_api/__init__.py", line 126, in check_in_list
  raise ValueError(
    ValueError: 'box-forced' is not a valid value for adjustable; supported values are 'box', 'datalim'
```

I have installed `scikit-image` exactly as recommended here:

https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/install.html.

I am on macOS Mojave.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see from the link, the example is from the outdated `0.12.x` version(s) of `skimage`, whereas `0.18.0` is current stable version. And, as the error message indicates, the error comes from this line:

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, 2, figsize=(8, 5), sharex=True, sharey=True,
                       subplot_kw={'adjustable': 'box-forced'})
```

Obviously, the handling of the `adjustable` member has changed in `matplotlib.pyplot` over the years. By simply removing the `subplot_kw` parameter at all, for example, the code runs perfectly fine:

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, 2, figsize=(8, 5), sharex=True, sharey=True)
```

In fact, that's also, what the [updated example](https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/auto_examples/applications/plot_thresholding.html#local-thresholding) from the `skimage` documentation looks like (second example there). Notice: You'll have to add two `import` statements on your own, since the given code there in incomplete.

Comment: Thank you so much! I have downloaded the script from here: https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/_downloads/939bd4a228ba1525a5e2896c819e2218/plot_thresholding.py and it seems to work (it shows all the algorithms results of the page you linked). How can I test the script with my own image though? Because in the script gets the image from data.camera() or data.page().

Comment: [`skimage.io.imread`](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.io.html#skimage.io.imread)!?